# Is there any aggregate function in mySql where range can be shown comparing two columns with counts

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

suppose I have data in a mySql table as followed:

```
+------+-------+------+
| Name | Start | End  |
+------+-------+------+
| A    | 1     | null |
| A    | 2     | null |
| A    | null  | 3    |
| B    | 4     | null |
| B    | 5     | null |
| B    | null  | 6    |
| A    | 7     | null |
| A    | 8     | null |
| A    | 9     | null |
| A    | null  | 10   |
+------+-------+------+
```

Now I need to show in result as followed:

```
+------+-------+-----+-------+
| Name | Start | End | Count |
+------+-------+-----+-------+
| A    |     1 |   3 |     3 |
| B    |     4 |   6 |     3 |
| A    |     7 |  10 |     4 |
+------+-------+-----+-------+
```

Here first A starts with 1 and ends with 3 therefore,

first row of the result should be: A (name) ---- 1 (start) ---- 3 (end ) ---- 3 (count)

second row of the result should be: B (name) ---- 4 (start) ---- 6 (end ) ---- 3 (count)

And then as A comes again with start value of 7 and end value of 10, so

third row of the result should be: A (name) ---- 7 (start) ---- 10 (end ) ---- 4 (count)

Can anyone help me about the query to get the result?

Comment: What are the criteria, you are just showing some data and no explanation of how you achieve the results.

Comment: @NigelRen, I haven't achieve the result yet but I want to get the result like this where I will have the names group by range of two columns (start - end) with count.

Comment: Here first A starts with 1 and ends with 3
therefore, first row of the result should be: A (name) ---- 1 (start) ----3 (end ) ----3 (count)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```sql
SELECT filtered.name, MIN(filtered.start), MAX(filtered.end), COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT t.name, t.start,t.end, @curRank := IF(t.name = @letterINIT, @curRank , @curRank + 1) AS rank, @letterINIT := t.name as letter
FROM test as t, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r, (SELECT @letterINIT := null) l
ORDER BY COALESCE(t.start, t.end)
) as filtered
GROUP BY filtered.name, filtered.rank
ORDER BY filtered.rank
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cd215/1

Comment: Thanks, it serves the purpose. But I'm concerned about the query time and if it's efficient in large table.

Comment: Indeed I have not tested the effectiveness, it is a first approach and you can benchmark it. 
However if the performance matters a lot, maybe you should consider adding some columns in the table to pre-calculate the data needed for the group by. 
Without the use case it is difficult to get in condition on the functional logic.